# javascript onclick not firing on button click

Tags: javascript, onclick, dojo, event-handling, event-binding

I am trying to call a JS function when the user clicks a button. But the onclick event is not being fired. The developer tools shows me the following error:

Error executing:

```
 function (/*Event*/ e){
        // summary:
        //      Handler when the user activates the button portion.
        if(this._onClick(e) === false){ // returning nothing is same as true
            e.preventDefault(); // needed for checkbox
        }else if(this.type == "submit" && !this.focusNode.form){ // see if a nonform widget needs to be signalled
            for(var node=this.domNode; node.parentNode/*#5935*/; node=node.parentNode){
                var widget=dijit.byNode(node);
                if(widget && typeof widget._onSubmit == "function"){
                    widget._onSubmit(e);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
ReferenceError
arguments: Array[1]
get message: function () { [native code] }
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set message: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
type: "not_defined"
__proto__: Error
```

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<td>
<button dojoType = "xwt.widget.form.TextButton" id = "pingButton" baseClass = "defaultButton" onclick = "onPing();">Ping
  </button>
   </td>
```

JS:

```
onPing : function() {
        alert('works');
    }
```

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: add `type="button"` to your `<button />`, as the code checks the `type` attribute.

Comment: nothing. even after adding type into my <button />, the same error is coming up

Comment: crap... should have said `type="submit"`

Comment: Also, try not to use onclick attributes.  Try binding the event in your code: `document.getElementById("pingButton").onclick = onPing;`.  It also appears your onPing function is part of an object.  In such a case you will need to fully qualify your function name: `myObject.onPing`

Answer (score 2):

In lieu of continuing a rather bang-head-against-table thread, I will explain to both the OP and others why he is having problems.

**Problem 1:** The OP did not post all relevant code.  The OP is apparently new to both OOP and SO and he made the fatal error of assuming less is more.  We can see that there is an `onPing` function which is part of an object as per the colon `:` syntax.  If he were to post all of his code, his javascript would look something like this:

```
var myObject = {
    onPing: function() {
        alert("works");
    }
};
```

It should be noted here that I am not sure what the name of his object is.  I used the name `myObject` so as to imply *"your object name here"*.

**Problem 2:** There is an onclick function which is defined inline with a button.  This is not good practice and can lead to bugs... especially when so many cut-and-paste javascript snippets are written inside of closure:

```
(function() {
    /* 
    This is an example of closure.  
    Any variables/objects/functions defined in here are not accessible to the outside world 
    */
})();
```

**Problem 3:** The code appears to rely on an attribute `type` with a value `submit`.  Therefore the button should have that attribute set:

```
<button type = "submit" dojoType = "xwt.widget.form.TextButton" id = "pingButton" baseClass = "defaultButton" onclick = "onPing();">Ping</button>
```

While a quick and dirty solution might be to declare a global function called `onPing`, this might cause problems with other libraries, makes the code more difficult to maintain, and is just plain ol' bad practice and should never be encouraged.  So lets explore a better solution which will do the following:

- Show complete working code
- Define objects within closure
- Bind events through code, not inline

Here goes...

```
<button type="submit" dojoType="xwt.widget.form.TextButton" id="pingButton" baseClass="defaultButton">Ping</button>

<script>
(function() {
    var myObject = {
        onPing: function() {
            alert("works");
        }
    };

    document.getElementById('pingButton').onclick = myObject.onPing;
}());
</script>
```

And to be super nice, we include a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/uJfRs/).

Answer (score -1):

This works

```
function onPing() {
        alert("this");
    }
```

Can leave button as it is....

```
<button dojoType = "xwt.widget.form.TextButton" id = "pingButton" baseClass = "defaultButton" onclick = "onPing();">Ping</button>
```

Comment: That does not solve the problem but provides a different solution.  The code is causing an error, and that's what he needs fixed.

Comment: @RyanWheale Sorry about that. I would have thought it makes little difference....

Comment: No need to apologize. I hate downvoting `:(` - but when a solution does not aim to solve the problem, then I feel it's the community's duty to make it known.  Can you explain why your answer *might* be able to lead him to a solution?  If so, I'll take it back.

Comment: @RyanWheale The reason I put up this solution was because I put the code into VS and ran it and FireBug gave me a JS error saying `SyntaxError: function statement requires a name [Break On This Error] onPing: function () { ...`  Therefore, I changed it to my answer and it worked.  Btw, are you sure your solution works. When I put in the button as provided above and then add the submit suggestion, I still get the same error.....   :S

Comment: I haven't provided a solution... but if you are referring to my comments above... I mention the fact that his `onPing` function appears to be a member of an object... and I told him to fully qualify the function name: `myObject.onPing`.  This would most likely solve his problem.  Defining an erroneous function just floating out in some scope (as you have suggested) is not a solution and only serves to cause more problems.

Comment: lol, i use the word 'solution' loosesly mate. I am asking if you have tried what you suggested. Because when I put it in and run it using your suggested `myObject.onPing` and change the type to submit and nothing else it does not work...  :S

Comment: Robin... there is obviously code missing.  His `onPing` method is part of an object, as per the colon `:` syntax.  However, he did not post all of his code... so I used `myObject` simply as an alias to the object of which `onPing` is a member.  His code should look something like this: `var myObject = { onPing: function() { alert("works"); } }` - except his object probably has a different name than `myObject`.

Comment: ... I understand what you mean re the code. Makes sense. lol. My interpretation was clearly a bit off in this case. Win some, loose some ` :P ` Have a good day hey! :)